# Open website pages and wordpress blog with the correct .htaccess settings

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website with the following structure

```
public_html
   files and folders like index.php and terms.php - this is what loads mywebsite.com
   blog folder
     wp-admin
     wp-content
     wp-includes
     index.php
```

When I now open mywebsite.com, it loads. When I open mywebsite.com/terms, it loads. When I open mywebsite.com/blog, it loads. But mywebsite.com/blog/my-first-post does not load.

According to wordpress I set this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now mywebsite.com/blog/my-first-post does load, but anything else after mywebsite.com/ does not. Neither mywebsite.com/terms nor mywebsite.com/dashboard/myaccount and so on. For some reason these pages seem to be in the blog now and obviously this is why they show a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this `.htaccess` file inside `public_html/blog`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please let me know if the problem persists.